# VS Code multiple views of same file WITHOUT splitting

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a way in Visual Studio Code to have multiple instances of the same file open, but **without** splitting the view?

(Sublime editor achieves this with "File > New View Into File")

Answer (score -3):

Just press the icon next to the `...` Icon (It looks like a split window), or press **Ctrl + \***. I hope this answered your question! :D

Edit: Sorry, I didn't read the whole thing since I came to this post from the best text editor article, lol. I don't think there is a way of doing that. Though I think you can make it yourself if you want to.

Comment: Thanks, but that just splits the editor area into multiple panes (and takes up a lot of real estate).  I'm looking for a solution that enables the same document in multiple tabs in the same pane.